# Form sometimes won't hide despite being in finally block

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my winform application I have a form for displaying the 'Please wait...' message along with a progress bar or some text. For performance reasons the Form is a singleton which is opened using BringToFront(), Show() and Refresh() and it is closed with Hide().

I'm using try...finally pattern to display this form and hide it.

```
try
{
WaitForm.Display();
// Some code
}
finally
{
WaitForm.Hide();
}
```

In some rare cases, the users reported that the form didn't close. Can you think of any reason why the form wouldn't close? The user interface is responsive when this happens.

Comment: Can you reproduce the bug ? I cant see why it isnt called ...

Comment: Is this all the code in finally block? Do you have some line of code before the `WaitForm.Hide();`?

Comment: @squelos: The code in a finally block is *always* called. The only way for `WaitForm.Hide()` not being called is that there's some code before the statment that exits the `finally` block (maybe throwing an Exception?) or that hiding the form causes an exception itself.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. From several hundred active users daily I get maybe one report a month. This is the only code in finally block.

Comment: Can I safely call Hide() several times with no consequences?

Comment: @Nezreli: Yes, usually you can call `Hide` as often as you want to.

Comment: You aren't posting the relevant code to fix this problem.  It sounds like you should be using a BackgroundWorker to do this.  Close the form when the worker completes.  At the very least, catch any exceptions.  Also try logging the `Hide()` method so you can verify that it is being called.

Comment: I'm catching any exceptions. None surfaced so far. I'll try to logging. Also, it seems that this only happens on Windows 7 machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, in windows application, for any UI refresh, its main message loop needs to be run. So in your case, if there is any tight loop/processing happening after this code block then form may not get hidden immediately.

Perhaps, you can yield the UI thread after the code-block so that UI can get refreshed. For example,

```
try
{
  WaitForm.Display();
  // Some code
}
finally
{
  WaitForm.Hide();
  Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: Not sure that this is the case. For example I have witnessed that the form didn't close and the user freely scrolled the datagridview below it. The wait form was used for a SQL query that populated the datagridview control.

Comment: @Nezreli, perhaps, call to `WaitForm.Hide` it-self is throwing an exception. You can confirm it by putting try-catch in finally block to catch and log the exception. One of the reason for hide to throw an exception could be that it has invoked on non-UI thread (or different thread than one on which form is created and shown) - however in such case, you should get the consistent issue with hiding the form.

Comment: The Application.DoEvents() method has solved the problem. Thanks.